# Auditing Sharepoint Document Library access/changes

Tags: sharepoint, audit

I have a client using SharePoint 2007 (MOSS) that wants to track access to the contents of documents libraries; mainly changes (adding/removing/changing files) but read access would also be good to track.

We've enabled the Sharepoint audit logging and tried a program called Logbinder, which gets the information but isn't quite what we need; it puts the audit information into the windows logs instead of into a report (and it crams all the information into a single field if exported from the logs) and it requires a lot of admin rights that we're not comfortable giving the program (It needs site admin rights, when it should just need to read the DB)

How can we get reports on who changes the contents of a document library out of SharePoint?

Comment: @DrStalker: do you need (for legal purposes/etc.) the audit log reports to be generated by a system that is not SharePoint, or would reports based in SharePoint work for you?

Comment: Reports based in SharePoint are fine if they have the needed information; this is for internal auditing & tracking of document access rather than for implementing a legally required process or preventing a compromise of the SharePoint servers. (The really secret docs are all encrypted before going into SharePoint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to turn on versioning.  This will give you a clean list of versions you can read through using either SPListItem.Versions or SPFile.Versions.  You would have to write code.

Answer (score 1):

With the disclaimer that I have never used it before (and have no affiliation with it...) This product seems to fit your needs:
http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/SharePoint-Audit.aspx

It generates reports off of the audit log data that are administered and viewed from within your SharePoint site.